# A root system of vectors in R^n admits a simple system; but does every finite set of vectors

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, root-systems

I'm reading about root systems in the context of finite reflection groups. As I understand it, every root system (a set $\Phi$ of vectors in $R^n$ with some nice properties) admits a *simple system*, i.e. a subset of $\Phi$ such that

1. the vectors in $\Phi$ are linearly independent;
2. every vector in $\Phi$ expressed as linear sum of the simple vectors has all non-negative or all non-positive coefficients.

My question is, forgetting about root systems, does every arbitary finite set of vectors in $R^n$ admit a simple system: ie some subset satisfying the two conditions above? I'm struggling to prove it, or to find a counter-example!

I'm not insisting that the coefficients be integers: partly because I can see this wouldn't be true generally, and partly because the book I'm following (Humphrey's) doesn't insist on it, and if I understand correctly we get some root systems where the integer condition isn't satisfied (eg Dihedral groups).

Thoughts I've had so far:

- If my intuition serves me right, then what we are trying to prove is that from any finite set of vectors, we can pick a linearly independent set such that all the other vectors fall into the "double cone" of the chosen vectors. To this end, we would want to pick nicely spread out vectors with obtuse angles so the cone is really wide.
- Hence, a counter example might use a set of vectors with lots of acute angles.
- A proof, if it exists, might follow the proof for root systems, and take a smallest subset of vectors satisfying condition 2) above. We would then have to show linear independence.
- We require the set of vectors to be finite, as some infinite sets of vectors won't have simple systems (eg, all of them in $R^n$).

Thank you for reading my question. Any thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Take $u$ and $\sqrt{2}u$ for instance. This is a finite set, but $\sqrt{u}$ cannot be expressed a sum at all (unless I am missing something ?).

Comment: As suggested by @AnthonySaint-Criq, you'd want to have all the vectors lie in a _lattice_ $L$ (free $\mathbb Z$-module of rank $n$ inside $\mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb R/L$ is compact). Then you avoid obstacles that are presumably less interesting.

Comment: You forgot the condition in (2) that the coefficients should be integers.

Comment: Good point to flag the integer condition Moishe! I'm relaxed about that, firstly because I can see it wouldn't generally be true, but secondly the book I'm reading (Humphrey's) doesn't insist on the crystollagraphic condition, so we get root systems where the integer condition isn't true, eg dihedral groups.

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq, in the example {u,sqrt(u)}, what I'm thinking is {u} would be a simple set, as {u} is a basis of R, and both u and sqrt(u) can be expressed as a linear sum of elements of {u} with all coeffecients non-negative or non-positive. Is that what you meant? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I assumed you means linear combinations over $\mathbb{Z}$ (and thus, asking that all coefficients are in fact in $\mathbb{N}$), since you talked about sums of vectors ! Then, my example is not working ! This is a nice question I am bookmarking, as now I want to know the answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should have required the subset $S$ of simple roots to be linearly independent, not $\Phi$ (otherwise, the solution is quite simple: Take $S=\Phi$).

With this in mind, there is a counter-example  already when $n=3$. Consider a pyramid $P$ in $R^3$ with tip at the origin and such that $P$ has quadrilateral cross-section with vertices $v_1,...,v_4$. Now, take your set $\Phi$ of vectors to be $\{v_1,...,v_4\}$.

Comment: thanks for pointing out my typo, yes I did indeed mean for S to be linearly independent. I'll fix.Great simple counter-example, that's exactly what I needed to wrap my head around this. Thanks!